# Why is h_addr_list (in hostent struct) typed as char** and not void*?

Tags: c, networking

I was trying to figure out a piece of code which constructs a hostent object, more specifically, the part of it's work that populates the h_addr_list array.

I was confused by the fact that the values that were assigned into the array were cast to `char*`, seeing as this array has nothing to do with strings as far as I read.

I noticed that the `h_addr_list` array is actually typed as `char**`.

The only place I saw that takes note of this fact is [section 9.7 in beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/gethostbynameman.html), but even there there's no explanation on why is it typed so.

Is there a reason that `h_addr_list` is typed as `char**` and not `void*`/`void**` (or anything else that might be a bit more informative)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char *` needn't necessarily refer to a C string, but also to a chunk of memory of known length that needs to be addressed by byte, presumably because it arrives from the network.

Before types like `int8_t` and `uint8_t` were added to C99, `char *` was the only practical way to refer to a contiguous byte array. In fact, `struct hostent` predates C89 which formalized the `void` type. If written today, the field would be declared as `void **` or possibly `uint8_t **`.

Comment: The orignal K&R C did not support the type `void` at all.

Comment: Well, I guess I should be a bit ashamed for not figuring that one out myself. Thanks!