# Are they different: converting type of pointer then get data AND getting data of pointer then convert datatype

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to use gethostbyname() for TCP connection. I don't really understand why the following two lines have different results:

```
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = (uint32_t)(*(hs->h_addr_list[0]));
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = *(uint32_t *)(hs->h_addr_list[0]);
```

The first line gets the data of the pointer and then converts datatype, while the second line converts the datatype first and then gets the data. My code is show below:

```
#include "net.h"

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    int fd = -1;
    struct sockaddr_in sin;

    if ((fd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0)) < 0)
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(-1);
    }

    struct hostent * hs;
    if((hs = gethostbyname(SERV_IP_ADDR)) == NULL)
    {
        herror("gethostbyname");
        exit(-1);
    }

    bzero(&sin,sizeof(sin));
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_port = htons(SERV_PORT);

    //sin.sin_addr.s_addr = (uint32_t)(*(hs->h_addr_list[0]));
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = *(uint32_t *)(hs->h_addr_list[0]);

    printf("%d:%d\n",(uint32_t)(*(hs->h_addr_list[0])),*(uint32_t *)(hs //
            ->h_addr_list[0]));
    if(connect(fd,(struct sockaddr *)&sin,sizeof(sin)) < 0)
    {
        perror("connect");
        exit(-1);
    }

    puts("client OK");

    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    int ret = -1;

    while(1)
    {
        bzero(buf,BUFSIZ);
        if(fgets(buf,BUFSIZ-1,stdin) == NULL)
        {
            continue;
        }
        do{
            ret = write(fd,buf,strlen(buf));
        }while(ret < 0 && errno == EINTR);

        if(strncmp(buf,"quit",strlen("quit")) == 0)
        {
            puts("client exits");
            break;
        }
    }

    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

h_addr_list is a char ** in the hostent struct.

So:

```
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = (uint32_t)(*(hs->h_addr_list[0]));
```

hs->h_addr_list[0] <strike>contains</strike> yields a pointer to char.

You dereference it, yielding a char, then cast that into a uint32_t.
That means that you take the first byte pointed to by hs->h_addr_list[0] and convert that into a 4-byte integer, thereby losing the subsequent 3 bytes.

You **do** get a number in your uint32_t, but it represents only a one-byte integer.

```
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = *(uint32_t *)(hs->h_addr_list[0]);
```

Here you take the char pointer, cast it to a pointer of uint32_t, and then dereference it.

That way you read all 4 bytes starting at hs->h_addr_list[0], which can directly be cast into your uint32_t. As long as you know that your hs structure has been properly initialized, this will work.

As a caveat: The resulting uint32_t value will be in network endianess, which might differ from your machine's endianess.

As long as the functions you pass that value in expect it so, fine. You should just be aware of it in the back of your mind.

Comment: The type of sin.sin_addr.s_addr is uin32_t. I'm trying to put the first network address of h_addr_list into sin.sin_addr.s_addr. The second line actually works, I can connect the client with the server.

Comment: What is the type of h_addr_list?

Comment: It's char **, like you said

Comment: Hm, yes, remembering things....are you sure the type of ....s_addr is is directly uint32_t? I would expect a typedef somewhere like this: typedef uint32_t in_addr_t; But anyhow, I'll edit my answer to better address your question.

Comment: I just figured out what's going on. h_addr_list is a 2-dimensional array. Every 4 elements of the array form up a whole address. Assuming the network address is 192.168.1.1, *(hs->h_addr_list[0]) is gonna get the first quarter of the address because char is 1 byte. Doing the cast (uint8_t)(*(hs->h_addr_list[0])) will get 192. If casting the pointer first, which is (uint32_t *)(hs->h_addr_list[0]), then every 4 bytes are combined. So dereferencing it will get full address.

Comment: Again, it's been a long time, but I do not think h_addr_list stores the IPs as strings; it does store them as an unsigned integer. (Or a list of unsigned bytes, which is kind of the same) Therefore you have functions to convert between the string format and the numerical representation of the IP address.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513878/why-is-h-addr-list-in-hostent-struct-typed-as-char-and-not-void                                                                         I found this helpful.